# PermanentRedirect while generating pre signed url

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am having an issue while creating a pre signed url from aws s3 using aws-sdk in nodejs. It gives me PermanentRedirect The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint.

```
    const s3 = new AWS.S3()
    AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: 'test123', secretAccessKey: 'test123'})

    AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'})

    const myBucket = 'test-bucket'
    const myKey = 'test.jpg'
    const signedUrlExpireSeconds = 60 * 60

    const url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
        Bucket: myBucket,
        Key: myKey,
        Expires: signedUrlExpireSeconds
    })
    console.log(url)
```

How I can remove this error to get pre signed url working. Also I need to know what is a purpose of Key.

Comment: Is the bucket actually in the us-east-1 region? I've only seen this issue when you configure the S3 client to use a different region than the one the bucket exists in.

Comment: @MarkB While creating a bucket I have selected Us Standard. I assume that us-east-1 falls in Us Standard.

Comment: Yes, US Standard == us-east-1.

Comment: @MarkB I have changed the region to oregon and it worked but it gives me now Access denied

Comment: You should be setting all the AWS config settings before you create any AWS clients. Move the first line where you create a `new AWS.S3()` down below the `AWS.config.update` lines.

Comment: If you are still seeing the permanent redirect, please show the response body xml and response headers as well.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I am not seeing the permanent redirect error because I have changed the origin, now what I am seeing is Access denied, I think it be assigning of IAM roles to a user

Answer (score 1):

1st - what is your region of the bucket? S3 is global service yet each bucket has region, while creating the bucket you must select it.

[image]

2nd - when working with S3 not in N.Virginia region there could be situations when internal aws SSL/DNS is not in sync yet. I had this issue multiple times, can't find exact docs related to this but issue is from nature of redirects, not found or no access. Then after 4-12h it starts to just work. What i happen to dig out about these issues is something related to internal AWS SSL/DNS related to S3 buckets that are not in n.virginia region. So could be it.

3rd - If you re-created buckets multiple times and re-using same name. Bucket name is global, even if bucket is regional. So could be again related to 2nd scenarios when previously within last 24h bucket was actually on different region and now AWS's internal DNS/SSL haven't synced yet.

p.s. Key is object's key, any object inside bucket has key. On aws console you can navigate "key" which looks like path to file, but it's not a path to file. S3 has no concept of directories like hard drives. Any path to file is a key of object. AWS console just splits object's key by `/` and displays as directories to have better UX while navigating the UI.

Answer (score 0):

As @luckas shared in https://stackoverflow.com/a/75068149/6191913

You'd better to specify the region where the bucket is when sharing by presign:

```
aws --profile me --region REGION s3 presign s3://BUCKET/file.zip
```